# org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException in a transactional method with shedlock and hibernate in a Spring Job

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, shedlock

I get many `org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` in a Spring Boot 2.1 service. I have a job with Spring's `@Scheduled`, where I save not much addresses in a PostgreSQL with Hibernate.

The delays are set to `fixedDelay = 5000L`, `initialDelay = 5000L`.
I use `net.javacrumbs.shedlock`, so the lock is persisted in the database and only one container will acquire the lock and call `publishBatch()`.

It looks like this:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddressPublisher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddressPublisher.class);

    private static final int MAX_LOCK_IN_SECONDS = 600;

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;
    private final AddressProducer addressProducer;
    private final LockProvider lockProvider;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000L, initialDelay = 15000L)
    public void publishModifiedAddresses() {
        Optional<SimpleLock> lock = lockProvider.lock(lockConfigurationForPublishModifiedAddresses());
        if (!lock.isPresent()) {
            LOGGER.debug("did not acquire lock for publishing modified addresss");
            return;
        }

        UUID jobUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        try(MDCConfig ignored = new MDCConfig(jobUUID)) {
            do {
                if (publishBatch()) break;
            } while (true);
        } finally {
            lock.get().unlock();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean publishBatch() {
        List<Address> modifiedAddresses = addressRepository.findByLastModifiedAfterLastPublished(100);
        if (modifiedAddresses.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Found no modified addresss. Going to sleep.");
            return true;
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Found {} modified addresss that will be published.", modifiedAddresses.size());
        modifiedAddresses.forEach(addressProducer::sendAddress);
        LOGGER.info("Found and published {} modified addresss.", keyValue("addressCount", modifiedAddresses.size()));
        return false;
    }

    private LockConfiguration lockConfigurationForPublishModifiedAddresses() {
        return new LockConfiguration("publishModifiedAddresses", Instant.now().plusSeconds(MAX_LOCK_IN_SECONDS));
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class AddressProducer {

    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    public void sendAddress(Address address) {
        address.setLastPublished(Instant.now());
        addressRepository.save(address);

        //Do Kafka stuff
    }
}
```

A part of the stacktrace:

```
message:  "Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task."
stack_trace:  "org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [<packagename>.Address] with identifier [aa17cf6e-110e-4b1a-8866-6647b42e9155]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [<packagename>.Address#aa17cf6e-110e-4b1a-8866-6647b42e9155]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:335)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.save(Unknown Source)
    at <packagename>.AddressProducer.sendAddress(AddressProducer.java:91)
```

I tried not to save every address, but collect the list and then call `saveAll()`. Also I read that this can be a flushing problem, but I can't test it, because I don't get the `EntityManager` and find no way to do the flush manually. Also I think that it should be handled correctly, if it's transactional.

Thank you!

Greetings

Comment: @Transactional does not work if the method (or class) is not proxy'ed. You call 'publishBatch' from the same class.

Comment: Okay, in `AddressPublisher` I now only have the job configuration (`@Scheduled` annotation). Then I call the `@Transactional` annotated method `publishBatch()` which is moved to `AddressProducer`. Their I lock, call the `sendAddress` method, where I modify my entites, but do not save them. I `saveAll` `modifiedAddresses` in `publishBatch`, which is the transactional method.

Comment: Please update the code changes you made in your question.